# Translating LINQ into different formats

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have a LINQ expression like this:

```
var queryResult = ppl.Join(items,
                    h => h.id,
                    i => i.ownerId,
                    (h, i) => new {h, i})
                .Select(x => new {humanName = x.h.name, itemName = x.i.name});
```

What's the easiest way to convert it into a syntax like this?:

```
from ppl
join items
...
select ...
```

Any tool you'd recommend?

Comment: Any particular reason for doing so as compiler understands both. Moreover, behind the scene query syntax is converted to lambda expression.

Comment: From Andrzej: *You can start playing with
[LinqPad](https://www.linqpad.net/)*

Comment: If you have to use joins, something is wrong with the entities. If you define relations and navigation properties, loading an instance of People will generate the proper SQL statements to load the `People.Items` collection. LINQ isn't a replacement for SQL

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Could be linq2objects.

Comment: Do you want help with this particular query or to find a general tool that convert from expression to query syntax?

Comment: It's just about a general tool for converting. My company coding standard requires us to use the second type, while I find the chain syntax much easier and more readable. The target here is to be able to convert the chain syntax into the sql-like-LINQ Query

Comment: @Skylerdw I think Re-sharper can convert between the two. But I can not say for sure.,

Comment: @Magnus, unfortunately, it can't, or at least I can't find this option anywhere :(. It can convert a foreach loop into LINQ query but that's about it.